# jQuery slideUp does not properly execute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div element `container` which contains another div with more `input type button` elements. When I `mouseout` the second div element I want it to hide itself, but it happens when I move the mouse from a button to another one.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="settings">
<input type="button" value="Logout" />
<input type="button" value="Staff Area" />
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#settings").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/cm4hE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6b96z/)***</kbd>

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#settings").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Using ***`mouseleave()`*** can solve your problem. A nice *[Different between mouseout() and mouseleave()](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/)* is shown here...

Hope it helps...!!

Comment: Easy approach, simple answer. Thanks sir. Also thanks for the link, I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use [mouseleave](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseleave.asp) instead of [mouseout](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseout.asp). This is because the mouseout event is triggered if a mouse pointer leaves any child elements as well as the selected element. See those pages for more information.

So your example above becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#settings").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `hover` instead of `mouseout`

```
$(function(){    
    $("#settings").hover(function () {
    }, function () {
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

edited for completeness

Comment: I hope you're putting it inside a `$(document.ready());` or a $(function(){});`

Comment: I always use `$(document).ready();` for safety purposes and code readability.